# Best solution for relational db design with different types of content

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

Edit: title is pretty broad. It would be more accurate as "Best solution for relational db design where users can post content, and the available fields would vary depending on the type of content".

I'm working on a website where users can post different types of content. All posts have text and a feed_id value relating it to another (many posts to one feed). Based on the idea that some posts will only contain text, what would be the best solution?

Ideas I've thought of so far:

- Add a table for each special type that refers to a post, leaving unreferenced posts to be text posts.

Problem: How would text-only posts be queried?

- Add a table for each type including text posts.

Problem: Doesn't seem very efficient. For every post found in text_posts, the post would again have to be found in posts to get the text field. Then again, this was already the case with special types like pictures. Is there a proper way to accomplish this with JOIN?

- foreign key in each post entry to each special type which can be null

problem: Lots of null fields, and rules have to be maintained by the application.

- a field representing the type of post

cons: rules have to be maintained by the application (case sensitivity, posts should only have a valid type), harder to query
pro: this field could also represent different views for similar content (i.e. I could make a value for post_type called "blog_entry" which is exactly the same as a text post, but have the application show the content it differently). This pro has a bit of a code-smell to it though...

Also, if it makes any difference, my application is written in PHP.

Edit: It seems that my first solution, "Add a table for each special type that refers to a post, leaving unreferenced posts to be text posts", would work fine if I queried all posts like this:

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.text, picture_posts.id, picture_posts.src FROM posts
LEFT JOIN picture_posts
ON picture_posts.post_id=posts.id
ORDER BY posts.date DESC
```

and then some pseudo-code for the application would look like this:

```
print(posts.title, posts.text);
if (picture_posts.id is not null) {
    showPicture(picture_posts.src);
}
```

Should I use this design?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very open-ended question. If you are doing this as an academic exercise, I'd recommend reading about database normalization and database normal forms.  If you are doing this to produce a functional website, it sounds like you are reinventing several wheels from scratch and your time would be better spent searching for an off-the-shelf solution that meets your needs.

Comment: This is for a functional website, but it's my own project (so I have all the time in the world). This website is going to be very much content-based, so having a lot of control over the database seems ideal. I agree this question is very open-ended, but I'm not looking for a direct "this is better" answer either; I'm looking for different opinions on database design for a website that works as described.

Comment: I think you need more background knowledge on database design to accomplish what you want.  For example, your first problem, "Doesn't seem very efficient", is simply not true.  I'm afraid any canned solutions you read are going to be misinterpreted through a filter of unfounded assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I do need more background knowledge on database design. I've only started reading a few things about relational database design recently, and in doing so I came up with a few ideas that would be applicable to the website I'm working on. I figured I'd ask other people what they think I should do, and if they have anything to add onto what I've already thought of. I don't believe all my claimed problems to be true; I put them there so people could correct me and elaborate if I'm wrong. What's a "canned solution" by your definition?